# Warning on executing "git rebase"

Tags: git, rebase

I tried to modify the commit message of an old commit using the following command.

```
git rebase -i HEAD~3
```

After editing the commit list displayed in the text editor (replacing `pick` with `edit`), I got the following warning.

```
Warning: the SHA-1 is missing or isn't a commit in the following line
```

Then when execuing `git commit --amend`, I got the following error and could not modify the commit message:

```
fatal: Could not open file .git/rebase-merge/done for reading: No such file or directory
```

What should I do to avoid these errors?

Comment: You just want to change the commit message? If so, try using reword command

Comment: The same error occurs when using `reword`.

Comment: It seems likely that your editor is damaging the "jobs to do" file in such a way that the rebase code can no longer read it. What editor are you using?

Comment: I'm using Sublime Text 3 on Windows. The configuration is: `editor = 'sublime_text.exe' -w`

Answer (score 0):

It said the file was missing so I just created the file:

```
vi .git/rebase-merge/done
:wq
```

Now when I do git status, it works!